# Is the following function eventually positive?

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

Consider the function $$E(m)={\sqrt [3] {3}}{m} - [{\sqrt [3] {3}}{m}]-{\frac{1}{m}}$$
Here $[x]$ denotes the *integer part* of the real number $x$ and $m$ runs through the positive integers.
Is the function $E(m)$ eventually positive for large enough $m$?
Calculations for small $m$ reveal that $E(3)<0$ and that $E(7)<0$. Other values of $E(m)$ seem to be positive. How do I approach this?
I know that the sequence $\{{\sqrt [3] {3}}{m} - [{\sqrt [3] {3}}{m}]\}$ for integers $m\geq 1$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. And sequence $\{1/m\}$ for $m=1,2,3,\cdots$ has $0$ as its sole limit point.
Not sure how to use this information to answer how $E(m)$ behaves!

Comment: Suppose there is a large $m$ for which the function is negative. What does that tell you about rational approximations of $\sqrt[3]3$?